# Get html of the outer element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have element as follows

```
 <div id="features" class="feature" data-id="1">
   <a href="http://www.google.com></a>
   <img src="/sample.jpg">
   <p> Sample content </p>
 </div>
```

I want to get outer html of the div without inner children as follows

```
  <div id="features" class="feature" data-id="1"></div>
```

How do i do it without jquery?

Comment: You may use:- `document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(false).outerHTML`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way without actually affecting the page (i.e. actually removing all of the children) is to **[clone the DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)**:

```
var featuresEl = document.getElementById('features');
var clonedEl = featuresEl.cloneNode(false); //False to not clone children
console.log(clonedEl.outerHTML); //Returns what you wanted, without inners
```

**[Demo (see console)](http://jsfiddle.net/3zxc0ucs/1/)**

Comment: Does `outerHTML` supported in all browsers?

Comment: It's supported down until IE4.0. (So yes, all browsers)

Comment: Okay. Why do we need to clone before outerHTML?

Comment: Because if you don't clone, and you clear the children from the *real* node, then the actual elements will be removed from the real page. You can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bfxpky3u/1/) demo, that you get the HTML, but also the elements are gone.

Comment: Hardly. Unless you do over 10,000 of them at once, I doubt you'll feel anything.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a nicer way.. but you could do this

```
var node = features.cloneNode(); // clone your element
node.innerHTML = ''; // empty the cloned version
console.log(node.outerHTML); // ouput
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtzzrfnL/

Answer (score 0):

To get only the element without any children try to get the Whole html and remove all the children:

```
$('#features')[0].outerHTML.replace( $('#features')[0].innerHTML,'')
```

bye